# How to return value back to parent page from window.ShowModelDialog?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm facing some issue with returning value back to the parent page.
Please kindly help.

I have a gridview that allow users to add new record at the  row, but users also can click on the Search button on the row, and I will show a pop up with the below code.

```
        TextBox txtCarNo = gvLookup.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNo") as TextBox;           
        System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        s.Append("<script language='javascript' id='SearchResult'> " );
        s.Append("var WinSettings = 'dialogHeight:400px ; dialogWidth: 550px ;center: Yes ;resizable: No;status: no'; ");
        s.Append("javascript: window.showModalDialog('Search.aspx?no=" + txtNo.Text.Trim().ToUpper() + "','',WinSettings); ");
        s.Append("</script > ");        

        if ((!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("SearchResult")))
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SearchResult", s.ToString());
        }
```

At the child page, there will be another gridview that shows the search result, and users can click on one of the row to return the number back to the parent page.
I thought of using Session to pass the value back, but when showing the ShowModalDialog, the code at the parent page already went through, meaning Session won't work on this scenario.

Please advise how do I return a value to the parent page.
Appreciate very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Example from Wrox](http://p2p.wrox.com/javascript/26755-return-value-showmodaldialog.html)

When you call showModalDialog you do this:

```
var oReturnValue = showModalDialog(....);
```

Within showModalDialog, assuming your textboxes have IDs of "txtForename" and "txtSurname":

```
<body onbeforeunload="terminate();">
function terminate()
{
  var o = new Object();
  o.forename = document.getElementById("txtForename").value;
  o.surname = document.getElementById("txtSurname").value;
  window.returnValue = o; 
}
```

Then continuing in your main window:

```
alert(oReturnValue.forename + "\n" + oReturnValue.surname);
```

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks a lot for your help. Where should I put the alert in the main window?

Comment: if you need the alert then it should go right after the showModalDialog() command.

Comment: Hi Danny. Actually after users select a number from the ShowModalDialog, I need to show the selected number into the footer row at the gridview in the main page. The problem that I'm facing is i do not know how to assign the selected number into the footer row. :)

Comment: you can use javascript or jquery to access the footer element and add the value to it directly e.g. $("#yourtable tfoot td.something").html(oReturnValue.forename); or use a label and set its value with document.getElementById("yourfooterlabel").Text = oReturnValue.forename. BTW, it's Ted, Danny edited the url link in my post that's why he appears next to my name :). post me your html markup of the footer and I can show you how to add it there.

Comment: OMG, shame on me...I'm so sorry, Ted.
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" >
<ItemStyle Width="50px" />
<FooterTemplate >
<asp:ImageButton ID="txtSearch" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/find.png" CommandName="SearchNo" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("No") %>' />
</FooterTemplate>
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:TemplateField>

Comment: I meant the HTML markup as it ends up on your browser. and please tell me which element you want your value to go to.

Comment: Hi Ted. I would like to the value to go to the row at appear in <FooterTemplate>.
From the source of browser, the element is this.
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvLookup$ctl05$txtNo" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvLookup_ctl05_txtNo" style="width:199px;" />

Thank you so much. :)

Comment: yes, I got you, could you please do a "view source" on your page and paste the html markup rather than the server template?

Comment: s.Append(" $('#"+ txtNo.ClientID +"').val('+ valuefrommodal +') ");

Comment: Hi Ted. In this case, what should I put in the valuefrommodal?
I'm sorry for asking too details...

Comment: I tried to added the code that you provided.
System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
s.Append("<script language='javascript' id='SearchResult'> " );
s.Append("var WinSettings = 'dialogHeight:400px ; dialogWidth: 550px ;center: Yes ;resizable: No;status: no'; ");
s.Append("javascript: var retVal =window.showModalDialog('WorkflowSearchCar.aspx?car_no=" + txtCarNo.Text.Trim().ToUpper() + "','',WinSettings);");
s.Append("$('#" + txtNo.ClientID + "').val('retVal') ;"); 
s.Append("</script > ");

But I got the below error.
Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Comment: have you added a jquery reference in your html head?

Comment: Hi Ted. I didn't added jquery reference, actually this is my first time using jquery, sorry for that.. haha... finally i got it done, thank you so much for your time, kindness and help... very very appreciate... :)